# how can I reduce font file size.?

Tags: css, fonts

I am developing a website. I very happy to use a font. But think is that it having more than 7 mega bite of size. so my website become little slow. how i can reduce it's size or how i will get similar font.?

Comment: Your font probably contains many glyphs that you don't need. Try including only whichever glyphs are required to display the language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend cufon : http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/. You can transform regular TTF to a file who will be used using javascript. Have fun !

Answer (score 2):

Try recreating your web font using [Font Squirrel's Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator):

- turn on expert mode
- uncheck options you don't need

What typeface are you using? Maybe we can recommend an alternative.

Comment: font files are  calibri,cambria,arnopro bold .